Deduplication tool which is able to only compare two directories against each other?
I tried rdfind and jdupes, and if I specify two directories for them, they both match not only files in one directory against other directory, but also files inside of one of the given directories against each other. I would like to exclude such results which reside in one directory only, and it would also be faster to avoid scanning them. But I couldn't find an option in neither of tools which allows that.

What should be the end result? Remove all files in dir2 for which there's a file with the same contents (what about name and metadata?) found in dir1?

Nope, I intend to hardlink them to conserve disk space. They were hardlinked already, but became physically duplicated after I moved them to another disk.

So, first of all, if you're doing this on XFS, or btrfs, you probably want deduplication using reflinks, instead of explicit hardlinks. duperemove does that for you.
Anyways, if this is really about hardlinking on a file system that doesn't support reflinks:
I'd probably be lazy and just go about this manually. I'm using zsh, with a little find magic you can achieve the same in bash. You will need xxh128sum, which almost certainly exists for your linux distro (in a package called xxhash, most typically). It'd look something like this untested mess that I'll let you test on your precious data (maybe start by prefixing the rm line with an echo, so you see what would happen):
#!/usr/bin/zsh

# make output somewhat reliable
export LANG=C

originals="$1"
shift 2

tmpdir="$(mktemp -d deduplicate.XXXXXXX)"

pushd "${originals}"
  # Checksum the originals
  xxh128sum --tag > "${tmpdir}/original.chksum"
popd

for directory in $@; do
  pushd "${directory}"
    # check the checksums in the target dir
    xxh128sum --ignore-missing -c "${tmpdir}/original.chksum" > "${tmpdir}/check"
  popd

  # for each identical-hash file
  for file in ${(f)"$(sed -n 's/^\(.*\): OK$/\1/p' "${tmpdir}/check")"} ; do
    # make sure this isn't just a hash collision (disappearingly small probability, but still).
    # if bytewise *un*-identical, skip ahead to next file
    cmp --quiet -- "${original}/${file}" "${directory}/${file}" || continue
    # else (i.e., identical!), remove target file and create hardlink
    rm -- "${directory}/${file}" && ln -- "${original}/${file}" "${directory}/${file}"
  done
done
# clean up
rm -rf -- "${tmpdir}"

You can save this to a file, make it executable (e.g., chmod 755 deduplicate.sh), and run it as ./deduplicate.sh /path/to/original/directory /path/to/copy [/path/to/second_copy] […].
